Identify this movie based on some terrorist group
I watched this movie 3 years ago in parts on TV .
This movie is based on a fight between Government and Terrorist group. Terrorist group have some kind of virus which can destroy anything.
In order to blackmail the Government, the Terrorists used this virus on the Effile Tower and it became dust. 
Even tourists became dust when they came in contact with the virus.  But the Government's team stopped the virus through some programming etc.

I think G.I. Joe: The Rise of Cobra could be what you're looking for. The Eiffel Tower is destroyed by a rapidly expanding cloud of metal-eating nanomachines:



To see some other places where the Eiffel Tower is destroyed check out this link regarding the Eiffel Tower in popular culture, on Wikipedia.
